# Multiple Methods, identical content

Tags: java

So I am working on some older code (written years ago), and I saw what I thought was an opportunity to improve it.  But I need to make my case as to why i want to change existing code, and need a better reason that "you shouldn't duplicate code".

So here is the issue..
We have a MessageSender class for sending JMS messages to multiple different queues.  But whomever wrote the code wrote the same method 11 times with the only difference basically being the name of the queue.

For example, the current code looks like this

```
    public void publishToQueue1(final Object messageContent, final Map<String, Object> jmsHeaders,final Map<String, String> headers) throws JMSException {
    logger.debug("sending to queue1 - some message blah blah");
    publishMessage(esbJmsTemplate, queue1.getQueueName(), messageContent, jmsHeaders, headers);
}

public void publishToQueue2(final Object messageContent, final Map<String, Object> jmsHeaders,final Map<String, String> headers) throws JMSException {
    logger.debug("sending to queue2 - some message blah blah");
    publishMessage(jmsTemplate, queue2.getQueueName(), messageContent, jmsHeaders, headers);
}

public void publishToQueue3(final Object messageContent, final Map<String, Object> jmsHeaders,final Map<String, String> headers) throws JMSException {
    logger.debug("sending to queue3 - some message blah blah");
    publishMessage(jmsTemplate, queue3.getQueueName(), messageContent, jmsHeaders, headers);
}

public void publishToQueue4(final Object messageContent, final Map<String, Object> jmsHeaders,final Map<String, String> headers) throws JMSException {
    logger.debug("sending to queue4 - some message blah blah");
    publishMessage(jmsTemplate, queue4.getQueueName(), messageContent, jmsHeaders, headers);    
}

public void publishToQueue5(final Object messageContent, final Map<String, Object> jmsHeaders,final Map<String, String> headers) throws JMSException {
    logger.debug("sending to queue5 - some message blah blah");
    publishMessage(jmsTemplate, queue5.getQueueName(), messageContent, jmsHeaders, headers);
}

... more methods that look like this.. 
... and on..
... and on..
and on...
```

I wanted to replace that with a method that looks more like this where queue name is a part of the parameter.

```
public class MessagePojo {
    private Object message content;
    private Map<String, Object> jmsHeaders;
    private Map<String, String> headers;
    private String queueName;
..setters and getters...
}

public void publishMessage(MessagePojo mpo) {
    publishMessage(mpo);
}
```

Could anyone suggest some sort of design/pattern principal for moving away from the old code (multiple identical methods) other than DRI (Don't repeat yourself)?

Comment: It's a little like the factory pattern except instead of returning a class your are channeling to a queue. You could also look at the Chain of Responsibility Pattern.

Comment: One way you could frame it is that the existing code is very 'bug-prone', it would be very easy to make a mistake when using it and call the wrong method and publish to the wrong queue. By refactoring the code into more idiomatic and clearer code, you are reducing the future maintenance cost of the product- less expensive developer-hours spent in the future debugging why messages aren't showing up in the correct queues. Developers are expensive, if you can save the company time they would otherwise spend debugging terrible code like this, you are saving money.

Comment: I'd consider passing the queue itself instead of queue name to avoid "stringly typed" code.

Comment: Karl, Thanks for the reply. I already tried the 'readability', 'debuggin' and 'maintenance' approach with no luck.

Comment: The [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) community could help you articulate arguments

Comment: Just do it, if you have to change something, invest some time to refactor. It is not a question of demanding for it. We are paid for writing software. Writing software consists of writing a test for 3 lines of codes and refactor them.

Comment: With the queue selection by method name the queues are pretty much hardcoded. So when in future a different queue needs to be addressed, it is not sufficient to create the queue and reconfigure the code. You really have to recompile.
This will show as technical debt when the OPS side of DEVOPS has no time to go back to DEV.